# How to change this multiple line graph into a bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a python code to generate multiple line graph. I want to change it to a bar graph, such that for every point(Time,pktCount) I get a bar depicting that value on that time.

code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\XYZ.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, group in df.groupby('Source'):
    group.plot(x='Time', y='PktCount', ax=ax,label=group["Source"].iloc[0])
ax.set_title("PktCount Sent by nodes")
ax.set_ylabel("PktCount")
ax.set_xlabel("Time (milliSeconds)")
#optionally only set ticks at years present in the years column
plt.legend(title="Source Nodes", loc=0, fontsize='medium', fancybox=True)
plt.show()
```

This is my csv file :

`Source,Destination,Bits,Energy,PktCount,Time
 1,3,320,9.999983999999154773195,1,0
 3,1,96,9.999979199797145566758,1,1082
 3,4,320,9.999963199267886912408,2,1773
 4,3,96,9.999974399702292006927,1,2842
 1,3,320,9.999947199998309546390,2,7832
 3,1,96,9.999937599065032479166,3,8965
 3,4,320,9.999921598535773824816,4,10421
 4,3,96,9.999948799404584013854,2,11822
 2,3,384,9.999907199998736846248,1,13796
 3,2,96,9.999892798283143074166,5,14990
 1,3,320,9.999886399997464319585,3,18137
 3,4,384,9.999873597648032688946,6,18488
 3,4,384,9.999854397012922303726,7,25385
 4,3,96,9.999919999106876020781,3,26453
 1,3,320,9.999831999996619092780,4,27220
 3,1,96,9.999828796810067870484,8,28366
 2,3,384,9.999823999997473692496,2,31677
 3,2,96,9.999804796557437119834,9,32873
 1,3,320,9.999787199995773865975,5,34239
 3,1,96,9.999783996354582686592,10,35370
 1,3,320,9.999766399994928639170,6,41536
 3,1,96,9.999763196151728253350,11,42667
 1,3,320,9.999745599994083412365,7,49060
 3,1,96,9.999742395948873820108,12,50192
 2,3,384,9.999742399996210538744,3,50720
 3,2,96,9.999718395696243069458,13,51925`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly collect values for x and y axis in two lists, then plot them separately:-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\XYZ.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x1, y1 = [], []
for i, group in df.groupby('Source'):
    #collecting all values in these lists
    x1.append(group['Time'].values.tolist()) 
    y1.append(group['PktCount'].values.tolist())

ax.set_title("PktCount Sent by nodes")
ax.set_ylabel("PktCount")
ax.set_xlabel("Time (milliSeconds)")

color_l = ['r', 'y', 'g', 'b']
i = 0
for a, b in zip(x1, y1):
    ax.bar(a, b, width = 400, color = color_l[i])
    i += 1

plt.legend(('1', '2', '3', '4'))
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: no it's not that simple, just like a scatter plot plots a point for a value(x,y) now what I want to do is instead of a point I need a bar on that point of time. hope you got it!

Comment: yes,i have checked it but all bars are in blue color. it's not possible to differentiate because 'source' column contains 4 values viz., 1,2,3 & 4 so that needs to be shown using unique colours. but thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Sourabh You can make separate lists for different different values of 'i'.

Comment: @Sourabh i have added explicit color list. If you want more colors, do this:- from matplotlib import colors, and then use colors.CSS4_COLORS or colors.BASE_COLORS